# Doubly IGrouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My problem is that I am trying to group data TWICE and have it in a single collection.
First group by name, second group each name group by time hourly. The final collection would be a list of lists of items, the outer grouped by name inner by time.

"DataCollection" is a class used for serialization of data.

```
//RawData already defined as List of Items

var groups = new List<IGrouping<string, Item>>();
foreach (IGrouping<string, Item> group in RawData.GroupBy(a => a.Name))
{
    groups.Add(group );
}
```

The above code works perfectly.
Below the code breaks during runtime on the foreach .

```
var data = new List<List<ChartDataCollection<Item>>>();

for (var i = 0; i < groups.Count; i++)
{
    data.Add(new List<DataCollection<Item>>());
    foreach (IGrouping<string, Item> hourGroup in groups[i].GroupBy(h => h.Time.Hour))
    {
        data[i].Add(new DataCollection<Item>(hourGroup.ToList<Item>())
        {
            name = hourGroup.Key,
        });
    }
}
```

My question is whether I am overlooking something minor or approaching the question wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you declare" var data = new List<List<ChartDataCollection<Item>>>();  " and use  " data.Add(new List<DataCollection<Item>>()) " won't that be a problem?

Comment: I think that should be fine as it is appending a new List to the outer List of data.

Comment: @Alex once the data is grouped by the second group by when it tried to apply to the foreach it breaks.

Comment: I don't know what your types are but Hour sounds like an int or long, not a string.

Comment: Please include the exception message. "It breaks" is not specific enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @mikez that did it, thanks for taking a second look at it for me and I will accept it you put that answer up. And I wish I could view exception but circumstances will not allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got

```
foreach (IGrouping<string, Item> hourGroup in groups[i].GroupBy(h => h.Time.Hour))
```

but it seems pretty likely that `Hour` is a numeric type (int or long) rather than a `string`.

A natural question is:

> Why doesn't the compiler catch this?

The compiler silently inserts a cast from the enumerator's type to the declared type of the loop variable (`IGrouping<string, Item>`) instead of checking the type like it might in an actual declaration. This is for historical reasons. Back before generics, collections were often not strongly typed. The C# team wanted it to be easy to use these collections in `foreach` loops, so the spec says that the compiler inserts a cast for you. We've been living with that ever since. In many cases, the compiler can still catch errors because, for example, you can't even attempt to cast an int to string (that could never succeed). However, here it is one interface, `IGrouping<int, Item>`, to another, `IGrouping<string, Item>`, which could succeed at runtime. All the more reason to use `var` in loop variable declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code snip, may help you.

```
var foo = from x in RawData
          group x by x.Name into g
          select
          {
              Name = g.Key
              ItemsByHour =
                  from i in g
                  group i by i.Time.Hour
          };
```

Comment: @RDC Linq by definition is declarative code. The explanation is the code.

Comment: Thank you for help, I wanted to suggest you **"if you just paste only code or only comment in the Answer post, SO community assume its Low Quality Post"** .. So Please explain how OP can use your code or how it can help him/her.

Comment: @RDC Sorry...I may have come across a bit rude. But the fact is I honestly can't comment on the code in a way that would add value. I always endeavor to write code that is self-documenting. Thus I honestly don't know how to comment on this in a meaningful way. Any comments would simply be the code, AGAIN.

Comment: You could for instance explain, why you merged both groups into a single query, while OP added the first group to a new list etc.

Comment: @CSharpie because all I did was write what the OP asked for in Linq? The code literally says "get from RawData, group by Name then Group by Time.Hour".